# Laravel Vue Js npm run dev url

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I tried using

```
npm run watch
```

and

```
npm run dev
```

But, unfortunately, i cant find the url of the app. Also, I had no problems with running the commands, the commands run successfully.
I tried these urls already:
127.0.0.1:8000
127.0.0.1:8080
192.0.8.101:8000 // My computers ip
192.0.8.101:8080 // My computers ip

Comment: Be specific and show us some relevant configurations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should build the Vue app using `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`, and you also need to serve the laravel application using `php artisan serve`.

In the browser, go to `http://localhost:8000` and it should work.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The application isn't served through any package.json scripts. It's a PHP application, and therefore needs to be served either through PHP itself or a proper Web server (NGINX, Apache, etc.).